# When running code using class named Clock to store time I get incorrect output. Problem seems to be when splitting the time up

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I'm writing a class Clock to store time. Something you should know about the Clock class. The class Clock should have three variables, for hours, minutes and seconds. Make sure that minutes and seconds are always between 0-59 (both included) and hours are between 0-23 (both included).
My code doesn't seem to be working properly because it gives me the wrong output when I run it. The #main cannot be changed and I can only changed the class Clock.

The expected output is:

```
Testing initialization:   
a = 00:00:00  
b = 12:23:53   
c = 18:03:21   
Testing set functions:    
d = 15:37:38   
Testing addition, subtraction and multiplication
e = b + c = 06:27:14
f = e - b = 18:03:21
g = b * 0.8 = 09:55:06
h = d * 2 = 07:15:16
Test get functions
e = 06:27:14
e.hours() = 6
e.minutes() = 27
e.seconds() = 14
Testing comparisons:
06:27:13 < 06:27:14
12:23:53 > 10:18:42
18:03:21 == 18:03:21
18:03:21 >= 18:03:21
12:23:53 <= 18:03:21
```

My output:

```
Testing initialization:
a = 00:00:00
b = 12:23:53
c = 18:03:21

Testing set functions:
d = 00:00:00

Testing addition, subtraction and multiplication
e = b + c = 06:27:14
f = e - b = 18:03:21
g = b * 0.8 = 09:55:06
h = d * 2 = 00:00:00

Test get functions
e = 06:27:14
e.hours() = 6
e.minutes() = 27
e.seconds() = 14

Testing comparisons:
06:27:13 < 06:27:14
12:23:53 > 09:55:06
18:03:21 == 18:03:21
18:03:21 >= 18:03:21
12:23:53 <= 18:03:21
```

My current code:

```
class Clock:
    """
    This class defines a Clock object with the hours, minutes, and seconds attributes, and includes methods for setting the time, 
    converting to seconds, creating a new Clock object from seconds, and performing arithmetic operations with other Clock objects.
    """
    def __init__(self, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0):
        """
        Initializes a Clock object with the given hours,
        minutes, and seconds. If hours is passed as a string in the format "HH:MM:SS", 
        it will be split and converted to integers.
        """
        if isinstance(hours, str):
            hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, hours.split(':'))
        self.__hours = hours
        self.__minutes = minutes
        self.__seconds = seconds
    
    def __str__(self):
        """
        Returns a string representation of the Clock object in the format "HH:MM:SS".
        """
        return "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(self.__hours, self.__minutes, self.__seconds)

    def set_hours(self, hours):
        """
        Sets the hours attribute of the Clock object to the given value, if it is between 0 and 23.
        """
        if 0 <= hours <= 23:
            self.__hours = hours

    def set_minutes(self, minutes):
        """
        Sets the minutes attribute of the Clock object to the given value, if it is between 0 and 59.
        """
        if 0 <= minutes <= 59:
            self.__minutes = minutes

    def set_seconds(self, seconds):
        """
        Sets the seconds attribute of the Clock object to the given value, if it is between 0 and 59.
        """
        if 0 <= seconds <= 59:
            self.__seconds = seconds

    def hours(self):
        """
        Returns the value of the hours attribute of the Clock object.
        """
        return self.__hours

    def minutes(self):
        """
        Returns the value of the minutes attribute of the Clock object.
        """
        return self.__minutes

    def seconds(self):
        """
        Returns the value of the seconds attribute of the Clock object.
        """
        return self.__seconds

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Adds the total seconds of the current Clock object and the other Clock 
        object and returns a new Clock object with the sum, wrapping around to 0:00:00 if the total exceeds 24 hours."""
        total_seconds = self.__to_seconds() + other.__to_seconds()
        return Clock.from_seconds(total_seconds % (24 * 3600))


    def __sub__(self, other):
        total_seconds = self.__to_seconds() - other.__to_seconds()
        '''return Clock.from_seconds(total_seconds)'''
        return Clock.from_seconds(total_seconds % (24 * 3600))


    '''def __mul__(self, factor):
        total_seconds = round(self.__to_seconds() * factor)
        return Clock.from_seconds(total_seconds)'''
    def __mul__(self, factor):
        """
         Multiplies the total seconds of the current Clock object by the given factor and returns a new Clock object with the product, 
         wrapping around to 0:00:00 if the total exceeds 24 hours.
        """
        total_seconds = round(self.__to_seconds() * factor)
        while total_seconds >= 24 * 3600:
            total_seconds -= 24 * 3600
        return Clock.from_seconds(total_seconds)

    def __to_seconds(self):
        """
        Converts the time of the Clock object to the total number of seconds and returns the result.
        """
        return self.__hours * 3600 + self.__minutes * 60 + self.__seconds

    @staticmethod
    def from_seconds(total_seconds):
        """
        Creates a new Clock object from the given total number of seconds and returns the result.
        """
        hours = total_seconds // 3600
        minutes = (total_seconds % 3600) // 60
        seconds = total_seconds % 60
        return Clock(hours, minutes, seconds)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        """
        Compares the total seconds of the current Clock object and the other Clock object and returns True 
        if the current Clock object is less than the other Clock object.
        """
        return self.__to_seconds() < other.__to_seconds()

    def __gt__(self, other):
        """
        Compares the total seconds of the current Clock object and the other Clock object and returns True if the current Clock object is greater than the other Clock object.
        """
        return self.__to_seconds() > other.__to_seconds()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        Compares the total seconds of the current Clock object and the other Clock object and returns True if they are equal.
        """
        return self.__to_seconds() == other.__to_seconds()

    def __ge__(self, other):
        """
        Compares the total seconds of the current Clock object and the other Clock object and returns True if the current Clock object is greater than or equal to the other Clock object.
        """
        return self.__to_seconds() >= other.__to_seconds()

    def __le__(self, other):
        """
        Compares the total seconds of the current Clock object and the other Clock object and returns True if the current Clock object is less than or equal to the other Clock object.
        """
        return self.__to_seconds() <= other.__to_seconds()





#main
print('Testing initialization:')
a = Clock()
b = Clock('12:23:53')
c = Clock(18,3,21)
print('a =', a)
print('b =', b)
print('c =', c)
print()
print('Testing set functions:')
d = Clock()
d.set_hours(37)
d.set_minutes(142)
d.set_seconds(938)
print('d =', d)
print()
print('Testing addition, subtraction and multiplication')
e = b + c
print('e = b + c =', e)
f = e - b
print('f = e - b =', f)
g = b * 0.8
h = d * 2
print('g = b * 0.8 =', g)
print('h = d * 2 =', h)
print()
print('Test get functions')
print('e =', e)
print('e.hours() =', e.hours())
print('e.minutes() =', e.minutes())
print('e.seconds() =', e.seconds())
print()
print('Testing comparisons:')
i = Clock(6,27,13)
if i < e:
    print(i,'<',e)
if b > g:
    print(b,'>',g)
if c == f:
    print(c, '==', f)
if c >= c:
    print(c, '>=', c)
if b <= c:
    print(b, '<=', c)
```

Comment: You're handling out-of-range inputs in a different way than the problem expects.  You simply ignore invalid values, but the expected output indicates that they should wrap around, instead.

Comment: ok can you make an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the expected output (of the *d* instance), your setters are incorrect. You only seem to consider valid values **inside of a timestamp**, but for example a value of ***3723* seconds is also valid** (representing ***1* hour *2* minutes and *3* seconds**), and those values must be combined (added) with the existing ones (excepting the smallest which must overwrite).

Therefore, your setters are buggy.
Here's the fix (only listing modified methods):

```py
# ...

    def set_hours(self, hours):
        self.__hours = hours % 24

    def set_minutes(self, minutes):
        h, m = divmod(minutes, 60)
        self.__minutes = m
        self.set_hours(self.hours() + h)

    def set_seconds(self, seconds):
        hm, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
        h, m = divmod(hm, 60)
        self.__seconds = s
        self.set_minutes(self.minutes() + m)
        self.set_hours(self.hours() + h)

# ...
```

Probably this is just a (fairly introductory level) exercise, but worth mentioning [[Python.Docs]: time - Time access and conversions](https://docs.python.org/library/time.html#module-time), which is specifically designed to handle time objects.

Comment: Thanks! Still this is wrong `12:23:53 > 09:55:06` but it should be `12:23:53 > 10:18:4` in "Testing comparisons:" idk what's wrong.

Comment: Then your  existing code doesn't match expected output. As you see, *g* is initialized to *09:55:06*, and between its initialization and the comparison (with *b*) **it's not modified**, so the expected output is incorrect (I don't know where you get that *10:18:42* from).

Comment: You're right I have taken care of it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So everything is working as expected?